# Expo Publishing Issue (Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting this error while publishing the app, but app runs fine any way in expo client. Any idea what causing it?

```
Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details
Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
Unexpected token in JSON at position 0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you create a project and  When you start a project do you get an error?

Comment: no I have been working on it and even I did publish it once before.

Answer (score 0):

Ran this and it worked

```
yarn cache clean
```